# Attempting to use the CASL ability conditions for a specific subject and I can't get the id checks to work

Tags: reactjs, casl

I'm attempting to use the CASL ability conditions for a specific subject and I can't get the id checks to work. I need to setup an ability the can be used on a set of ids. Then in the UI ability check check an id of an object to see if it should be rendered. Does anyone have a React TS example?

Ability setup:

```js
can(['read', 'create', 'edit', 'delete'], 'Project', { projectIds: [1, 2, 3] });
```

Ability check:

```js
ability.can("read", { type: 'Project', projectIds: [ project.id ] })
```

Thanks.

Expecting true when the project.id is in the list.

Comment: Please read the docs. The conditions u use is incorrect. You need to use $in